# Excel Button Color Version Behavior Issue

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having issues getting the colors within excel to show correctly between two versions of excel.

I have a set of buttons on a worksheet used to represent user selections.  I save this in Excel 2013 and when it's reopened in Excel 2007, the colors go wacko.

Black (0, 0, 0) gets changed to Turquoise (0, 255, 255) - Blue (0, 0, 255) gets changed to Olive (128, 128, 0) and Grey gets changed to something else entirely.

Does anyone have any experience with this type of behavior?  The color of the button text is set via VBA, as is its enabled state, which is used to determine whether or not the button event should fire (since its click is called regardless in Excel 2013.)

Comment: Always helps to show the actual code you're using.

Comment: TimWilliams: agreed. Alexander: perhaps you have to check color settings are identical or not. First, post what have you tried.

Comment: I'm getting the Button object from the shape object on the worksheet.  Then I'm setting its .Font.Color.  In 2007, I set .Font.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbBlack and it makes it teal!  Mousing over the color after the fact shows the color for teal, not black...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to abandon the color approach and use ColorIndex.

For the systems that this impacts, the color schemes match consistently.

It's vexing that it does this, but I'd rather move beyond this than spin my wheels on it for an eternity.

If I step through debugging it and use a very clear value of `0` and it passes that execution point without error, and **doesn't** set it to the value that was expected, then I can only surmise that the it was a bug in that version of excel, but was fixed in 2013.

If anyone has further context to add to this in the future, please do.